# Making Silverlight 4 Custom NumberBox Blank without clearing the binding

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, custom-controls

I am trying to create my own very simple NumberBox inherited from TextBox that validates the input on lost focus and formats the value based on the specified decimal places. All works well until someone puts some invalid value.

In case of invalid value, I would like to make the NumberBox blank and not 0.0. Resetting it to a valid value like 0.0 will skip the required field validation check I have in my code.

I tried this.Text = "" but that triggers binding exception "Input String not in correct format"

If I try this.ClearValue(TextProperty), it clears the textbox but removes the binding too. Any idea how to achieve this or a better NumberBox other than the toolkit one?

```
public delegate void ValueChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
    public class NumberBox : TextBox
    {
        public event ValueChangedHandler ValueChanged;

        public NumberBox()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TextBox);
            this.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(NumberBox_LostFocus);

        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DecimalPlacesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DecimalPlaces",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(NumberBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(2));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MaxValue",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(NumberBox),
    new PropertyMetadata(Double.MaxValue));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MinValue",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(NumberBox),
    new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

        public int DecimalPlaces
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)this.GetValue(DecimalPlacesProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                base.SetValue(DecimalPlacesProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public Double MaxValue
        {
            get
            {
                return (Double)this.GetValue(MaxValueProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                base.SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public Double MinValue
        {
            get
            {
                return (Double)this.GetValue(MinValueProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                base.SetValue(MinValueProperty, value);
            }
        }

        void NumberBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double result;
            //if (this.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            //    return;

            if (double.TryParse(this.Text, out result))
            {
                result = Math.Min(result, this.MaxValue);
                result = Math.Max(result, this.MinValue);

                this.Text = Math.Round(result, this.DecimalPlaces).ToString("N" + this.DecimalPlaces);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    //this.Text = Math.Min(this.MinValue, 0.0).ToString();
                    this.ClearValue(TextBox.TextProperty);
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            if (ValueChanged != null)
                ValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the property directly or calling ClearValue actually overrides whatever is on the TextProperty, which could be, a BindingExpression. What you really want to do is just set the value, without really changing what's in there. Sounds confusing and the whole DependencyProperty subsystem is. Basically replace ClearValue for the following

```
this.SetValue(TextProperty, String.Empty)
```

You could find an explanation [Introduction to Dependency Properties](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-introduction-to-dependency-properties) and [Force a binding to update](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-forcing-a-binding-update). Both are for WPF, but relevant. UpdateTarget doesn't work in Silverlight though (solution coming).

That said, this approach still has a flaw. That's that your source (the object you bind to) will still have the latest valid value, even when according to your UI the value is . To fix this, if you were in WPF you would simply call UpdateTarget to get the latest valid value from the source and update your target (textbox). Silverlight doesn't support this, but there's a nasty way around this limitation: re-setting the binding.

Instead of ClearValue your code will look like this:

```
this.SetBinding(TextProperty, this.GetBindingExpression(TextProperty).ParentBinding);
if (double.TryParse(this.Text, out result))
{
    result = Math.Min(result, this.MaxValue);
    result = Math.Max(result, this.MinValue);
    this.Text = Math.Round(result, this.DecimalPlaces).ToString("N" + this.DecimalPlaces);
}
```

The last block is duplicated with the start of your method since we might need to reformat the string after we get the latest valid value. It might be worth creating a method to do this.

Hope this helps.

Miguel

Comment: Good insight. Will try it and let you know.

Comment: this is the best answer I got